# Positioning a bing maps control on a web page

Tags: html, layout, bing-maps

I'm trying to add a bing maps ajax control (v7) to a web page.  I can add the control using the boilerplate from the bing maps help - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427624.aspx with this as my map div.

```
<div id='mapDiv' style="position:relative; width:400px; height:400px "></div>
```

and this as my map initialization:

```
map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapDiv"),
    {
        credentials: "BING_MAPS_KEY",
        center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(45.5, -122.5),
        mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.road,
        zoom: 12
    });
```

The behavior I'm seeing is that if I use postion:static it takes up the whole page, if I use position:absolute everything appears to work, but I would then have to manually position everything else (I think).  If I use position:relative, it doesn't seem to take everything into account (e.g. the control will overlap its previous siblings and its later siblings will overlap the control).
 I'm a programmer, not an HTML expert so maybe there is something fundamental that I'm missing about the layout properties.

I've tested the code in IE and Chrome.  I've also noted that the rendering of the map seems to be using img tags that have position set to absolute, so maybe I need to tell it not to do that somehow?  But I looked and didn't see properties on the map control that would help but perhaps I'm missing something there?

Answer (score 1):

You should use position of relative or static. If rendering looks odd chances are you are missing the required meta tag and doctype values that is documented in the link you provided. This is the number one cause of rendering issues when using different browsers. It's pretty easy to get the map setup on your page. As an additional resource take a look at the interactive SDK: http://www.bingmapsportal.com/ISDK/AjaxV7 If you press the HTML button for any of the samples it will provide you with the full HTML that you can copy and paste. These should work without any issues in any major browser. If you are still seeing significant rendering issues then it is possible your browser is in compatibility mode. When this happens IE renders pages using IE5 standards which is not only really old but not supported by Bing Maps.